# How to handle Python subprocess `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2]`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm struggling to manage an error that occurs whenever I try to run this program on Windows 10:

```
import ffmpeg_streaming
from ffmpeg_streaming import Formats, Bitrate, Representation, Size
import subprocess
import sys

def monitor(ffmpeg, duration, time_):
    per = round(time_ / duration * 100)
    sys.stdout.write("\rTranscoding...(%s%%) [%s%s]" % (per, '#' * per, '-' * (100 - per)))
    sys.stdout.flush()

video = ffmpeg_streaming.input('http://freja.hiof.no:1935/rtplive/_definst_/hessdalen03.stream/playlist.m3u8')

_360p = Representation(Size(640, 360), Bitrate(276 * 1024, 128 * 1024))
_480p = Representation(Size(854, 480), Bitrate(750 * 1024, 192 * 1024))
_720p = Representation(Size(1280, 720), Bitrate(2048 * 1024, 320 * 1024))

hls_stream = video.hls(Formats.h264(), hls_list_size = 1, hls_time = 60)
hls_stream.representations(_480p)
hls_stream.output('C:/Users/Documents/mashpy/VideoAnalytics_Mediaserver/ffmpeg_exec_test/video_fragments/hl_test.m3u8')
```

The error message contains text:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Documents/mashpy/VideoAnalytics_Mediaserver/ffmpeg_exec_test/capture.py", line 20, in <module>
    hls_stream.output('C:/Users/Documents/mashpy/VideoAnalytics_Mediaserver/ffmpeg_exec_test/video_fragments/hl_test.m3u8')
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_media.py", line 82, in output
    self._run(ffmpeg_bin, monitor, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_media.py", line 93, in _run
    with Process(self, command_builder(ffmpeg_bin, self), monitor, **options) as process:
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_process.py", line 57, in __init__
    self.process = _p_open(commands, **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\ffmpeg_streaming\_process.py", line 28, in _p_open
    return subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(commands), **options)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Specified file not found
```

No idea what misses here. Primarily I set up PATH, same program was running perfectly un Ubuntu 18.04. How would you deal with that?

Comment: Are you sure the address is correct? "C:Users/" might be the case for one computer, but for another, it could be something else.

Comment: I used both plain and back slash, all the same error.

Comment: Could it be that the module is not properly installed?

Answer (score 0):

add `r` before the path name in the last line

```
hls_stream.output(r'C:/Users/Documents/mashpy/VideoAnalytics_Mediaserver/ffmpeg_exec_test/video_fragments/hl_test.m3u8')
```

Comment: Thanks for response. Pitifully, it doesn't seem as a case here. The error remains.

Comment: If you are sure that the path actually this should have worked. You could try python os package. hls_stream.output(os.path.join(r'C:/Users/Documents/mashpy/VideoAnalytics_Mediaserver/ffmpeg_exec_test/video_fragments', 'hl_test.m3u8'))

Comment: I also think that your path might be incomplete. 'C:/Users/Documents' should be 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents', where xxxx is your username.